# pg.connect not working but psql is for local postgres db. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

When attempting to connect to a PostGres database from a web app, it doesn't work.

When trying from the terminal with psql, it does.

What am I doing wrong?

pgconnect3.js testing script:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var winston = require('winston');
var conString="postgres://postgres:test123test@localhost:5432/uaa_client";
winston.level = 'debug';

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    winston.debug('Error connecting to Postgres');
    winston.debug('err', err);
    return 1;
  } else {
    winston.debug("Successfully connected");
    client.query("SELECT * FROM uaa_client", function(err, result){
      done();
      if(err) {
        winston.error('Error reading from Postgres');
        return 1;
      }
      else{
        winston.info('Results: ', result);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The error it reproduces:

```
$ node pgconnect3.js 
debug: Error connecting to Postgres
debug: err error: database "uaa_client" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (/Users/patricklunney/Sites/testing/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/patricklunney/Sites/testing/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:381:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/patricklunney/Sites/testing/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:117:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

OK, so the database doesn't exist one might think. Not so fast.

```
$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W -d uaa_client
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.5.2, server 9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

uaa_client=#
```

What gives? I can connect to uaa_client in psql, and it also is visisble in pgAdmin3.

[image: Here is a pic of pgAdmin3]

pg_hba.conf file:

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# plain TCP/IP socket.
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives
# a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have
# to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can
# use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.

# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

# CAUTION: Configuring the system for local "trust" authentication
# allows any local user to connect as any PostgreSQL user, including
# the database superuser.  If you do not trust all your local users,
# use another authentication method.


# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the settings in pg_hba.conf 
Turn on logging in Postgresql and it might tell you more

Comment: Here is the pg_hba.conf file (added to original post). It looks like all connections are accepted from all users? In the logs I see a lot of this: `LOG:  invalid length of startup packet`

Comment: ok, check postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = 'localhost,10.179.45.23,173.203.110.212'             # what IP address(es) to listen on;

or

listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;

(and restart postgres of course)